# O "grace period" foi removido?

Tags: suporte, edição

Normalmente quando respondendo a uma pergunta o sistema não distingue edições feitas nos primeiros 5 minutos. Passados esses 5 minutos qualquer edição é registada no historial de edits e fica visível também no POST.

Mas enquanto esse *grace period* não tiver passado não são registados edits. Ora [na minha ultima resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56061/129) isso não aconteceu... o *grace period* nunca existiu e os edits estão registados no [historial de edits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/56061/revisions).

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O *grace period* foi removido ou é bug?

<sub>PS. editei agora a pergunta também para ver se acontece o mesmo aqui, e **sim acontece!**...</sub>

Comment: Grace *period*, não?

Comment: @bfavaretto corrigi e o edit gerou o comportamento aqui também.

Comment: Será que acontece sempre que editar pela segunda vez?

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que é a partir do 1o minuto. Mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O *grace period* não foi removido, mas sua lógica foi modificada essa semana, pra deixar mais claro quando edições ocorrem por conta de alguma outra atividade na pergunta.

As novas regras determinam que edições vão deixar histórico quando:

- Se passaram mais de 5 minutos desde a última alteração.
- Um comentário foi adicionado ao post depois da última edição, por alguém diferente do editor.
- Uma resposta foi adicionada à pergunta depois da última edição
- A edição anterior é uma reversão
- A nova edição é uma reversão

Fonte: [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/175506)

No caso da sua resposta, há um comentário criado entre a criação da resposta e sua primeira edição, o que "invalidou" seu *grace period*.
A mesma coisa aconteceu nessa pergunta no Meta, porque coincidência pouca é bobagem :D

Comment: Nossa, ficou bem mais complicado!

Comment: @bfavaretto Um pouco, mas é basicamente: não tem *grace period* se tiver alguma alteração no contexto do post nesse meio tempo

Comment: Entendi, e suponho que a intenção seja evitar perda de contexto quando o usuário editava a pergunta nos primeiros 5 minutos e acabava invalidando a resposta de algum usuário estilo The Flash (FGITW).

Comment: @bfavaretto Exatamente. Assim não fica parecendo que quem comentou/respondeu cometeu algum erro bizonho